# RMarkdown Formattable Styling From kableExtra renders html code - not formatted value

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra, formattable

When using kableExtra's cell_spec function, I cannot get the rmd document to format the target cell correctly. I can see the html format being applied, but it is rendering the html code itself, not the formatted value. I'm trying to format the p-value of a simple summary stats output.

What ends up rendered in the .html file is below:
[image: rendered-table]

I'm doing the same thing as below but with my own real data. For reference, this chunk produces the same problem.

```
mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column('car') %>% 
  select(car, mpg, disp, hp, wt) %>% 
  mutate(wt = ifelse(wt < 2, 
                     kableExtra::cell_spec(wt, color = 'red', bold = TRUE), 
                     wt)) %>% 
  kableExtra::kable() %>% 
  kableExtra::kable_styling()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`kableExtra::kable(escape = F)` is what you want:

```
library(kableExtra)
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column('car') %>% 
  select(car, mpg, disp, hp, wt) %>% 
  mutate(wt = ifelse(wt < 2, 
                     kableExtra::cell_spec(wt, color = 'red', bold = TRUE), 
                     wt)) %>% 
  kableExtra::kable(escape = F) %>% 
  kableExtra::kable_styling()
```

Comment: That's it - thank you.

For others: [the package documentation](https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_html.html#celltext_specification) clearly says this. I missed it or did not look for the right things.

Answer (score 1):

The code in the accepted answer no longer works in recent `kableExtra` versions, because `kableExtra::kable` is now identical to `knitr::kable`.  To get it to work in the current `kableExtra` version 1.4.0, use `kableExtra::kbl` instead:

```r
library(kableExtra)
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column('car') %>% 
  select(car, mpg, disp, hp, wt) %>% 
  mutate(wt = ifelse(wt < 2, 
                     kableExtra::cell_spec(wt, color = 'red', bold = TRUE), 
                     wt)) %>% 
  kableExtra::kbl(escape = F) %>% 
  kableExtra::kable_styling()
```

Comment: Thank you. For more information see https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues/811#issuecomment-1912363119